# The Docker image of ROS is unusable?

Tags: docker, ros

So, I pulled the ros container from docker hub, using

```
docker pull ros
```

which got me the latest docker 'foxy' version.

I proceeded with *the* [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker) on starting the docker container of ROS. I could successfully start the container and connect to it. It's a small little tutorial. Nothing long nor complicated.

The penultimate step in that tutorial asks for sourcing gthe setup.bash file, which I did and received no errors. (Actually nothing at all. Neither success, nor failure came up).

```
source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash
```

And after that, to taste the sweet fruit of my hard labour I entered the final command (as mentioned in the tutorial),

```
rostopic list
```

which returned *to my surprise*,

> rostopic command not found

I proceeded then to enter at the terminal `roscore`, `roscd`, etc and none of them worked. All of them were not found.

I did try to just run that setup script myself, from the terminal without using `source`, like:

```
$ /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
```

(after changing the permissions of course), which brought little change to the situation.

I looked in at the docker page for [ros](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros) and nothing helpful was to be found there. Plenty of instructions there about how to build my own docker image for ROS, but that is not what I want to do right now, I guess.

I googled and the hits on the first page were:

1. [this](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker) (the original tutorial which I am anyways following),
2. [this](http://wiki.ros.org/docker) (something general about docker)
   and,
3. [this](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI) (about how to
   run GUI with Docker - not there yet frankly),

which begs the question, what good is the container if I have to install everything myself anyways by following their other tutorial?

Or do I not understand something here? If someone could throw some light on it, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your container has ROS2, not ROS1. Try

```
ros2 topic list
```

If you want to get the ROS1 version instead, try pulling and running a different image instead:

```
docker pull ros:noetic-robot
docker run ros:noetic-robot
```

## Context

The tutorial you are following was written some time ago, when the default container used ROS1. The new `latest` container uses ROS2 (in your case, Foxy). ROS2 doesn't have the same command names. `rostopic` does not work, and there isn't even a master, so `roscore` would make no sense!

The good news is, the tutorial page is a wiki, so I've already updated it to make it (at least slightly) clearer. If you have ideas for how to improve it, you could also make an account and do so.

Comment: Thanks! Let me test that and get back to you here.

Comment: Indeed. It is as you say. Thank you for your time and the explanation. `ros2` works for me.